# How do you produce the number 5, using only 3 eights?

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

How do you produce the number 5, using only 3 eights? The 4 operations (+ - x and division) + square root and factorial are allowed but no extra numbers (no squaring).

Answer (score 12):

If you'll allow my little trick with the decimal point here, how about

> $$ \frac{\sqrt{8+8}}{.8} = 5$$

Comment: Excellent - that will do nicely!

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

> $\LARGE8-\sqrt{\frac{8}{.\overline{8}}}=5$

Comment: Using repeated decimals seems to either be introducing extra numbers or an extra operation, both disallowed by the question

Comment: That bar is not an operation.  It is a symbol used in the numerical notation, just like the decimal point.